# Verify that the application is a random variable (real)

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $\mathcal{F} =\{\emptyset, \{1 \}, \{2, 3 \}, \Omega  \}$ with $\Omega=\{1, 2, 3\}$, for $A \in \mathcal{F}$ we define:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & \text{if $w\in A$}\\ 
0 & \text{if $w\notin A$}
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

we can see if $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $X(w)=w^{2}$ is a random variable. I think that is not a random varible.

$X$ is said to be a random variable if for all $A \in \mathcal{B}$ we have that $X^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{F}$, In our case there must be an event s.t. $X^{-1}(A) \notin \mathcal{F}$, note that

$X^{-1}((- \infty, x])=\{w \in \Omega: w^{2}\in (- \infty, x] \}$

But here, what could be the element of the Borelian that does not return the inverse image of an element of the sigma algebra? any suggestions? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
    X^{-1}((-\infty, 4]) = \{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \le 4\} = \{1,2\} \not\in \mathcal{F}
$$